# Could not load file or assembly 'Noesis.Javascript.dll'

Tags: javascript, asp.net, windows, c#-3.0

I am trying to run java Script code in Asp.net using Noesis.Javascript.dll, but I faced Following error msg so any one can help me to resolve this issues.

> {"Could not load file or assembly 'Noesis.Javascript.dll' or one of its dependencies. The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B1)":"Noesis.Javascript.dll"}

Thanks

Comment: Can you see anything in the application event log? There's instructions for sxstrace in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2006/04/14/576314.aspx) if you're having trouble with it - what do you get from that?

Comment: May be that Noesis.Javascript.dll references other unmananged dll:s  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eldar/archive/2006/06/07/621501.aspx which it cant find. You can use ndepends to find which dll:s Noesis.Javascript.dll references. You may also use filemon to see which files the program is searching for.

Answer (score 5):

I had this error during runtime, and when I used **sxstrace.exe** to get a more informative error message dump, it turned out that Noesis.Javascript.dll wanted an *exact* version of the C++ Redistributable Package, **Microsoft.VC90.CRT.dll**, namely version 9.0.30729.6161
I got the right version at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26368

But do learn to use SxSTrace to see if that is your exact issue. An okay introduction to using the tool is here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2006/04/14/576314.aspx

Answer (score 4):

In our case (using version 0.7 of the library), we had to install the 2010 version of the C++ Redistributable:

x64: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=14632

Comment: I have a windows server 2012 64bit, but I actually had to install the x86 version for it to function properly. Thanks